# IIS Rewrite with # sign

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7.5

I have a url cars\model\BMW\index.html#2 and I am trying to redirect it to cars\model\PDF\BMW.html#page2 is there anyway to get this working?

> Is there anyway to find out if the URL has a # sign in IIS?

```
<rule name="InboundRuleTrailingPageNumber" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
     <match url="cars\/model\/(\w+)\/index.html(\w+)" />
        <conditions trackAllCaptures="false">
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="cars\/model\/(\w+)\/index.html(\w+)" negate="true"/>
        </conditions>
         <action type="Redirect" url="/cars/model/content/PDF/{R:1}.pdf#page={R:2}" logRewrittenUrl="true"/>
</rule>
```

Comment: `#` is used by the web browser to navigate within a page, so usually the browser won't send it in HTTP requests to your web server.

Comment: @LexLi is there anyway around it using the UNENCODED_URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`#` is pure client side behavior. If you test it via web browser.

[image]

You will see that IIS even didn't send #2 to IIS server.
[image]

If I try the same operation via fiddler composer,

[image]

[image]

And you can see that HTTP-API will take over this request and return 400 bad request directory. IIS did not event receive this request.

[image]

I think You shouldn't try to rewrite this on client side.